# Laravel eloquent one to many relationship data not showing

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have two tables,
**Student table** 
which have column (id, family_id,name,class,section)
**Family table** 
which have column (family_id, mobile_no, profession)

--
i have created two models.
**student model:**

```
class student extends Model
{

}
```

and
**family model**

```
class family extends Model
{
  public function student()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\student');

    }
}
```

--
i am able to show all data from student table, 
my controller is:

```
public function index()
    {
       $finddata = student::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
      return view('students.index')->with('finddata', $finddata); }
```

--
**what i tried**
in family model:

return $this->hasMany('App\students');

**what i want;**

- i want to connect family model with student model..
- index page will have all students name only. which i have already done
- when i click on student name it should show, all information about particular student, and his family information. right now it's only showing information from student table.

Comment: define relationship function in Student model:       public function family()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Family');

    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the student model:

```
class student extends Model
{
    public function family(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Family::class,'family_id');
    }

}
```

Then you can access family information in Blade by:

```
{{$student->family->mobile_no}}
{{$student->family->profession}}
```

You should better use `artisan` commands to generate models and controllers, so that you get automatic templates that follow naming conventions, such as uppercase Class names.

Comment: i tried your solution, but i got this error, "Undefined variable: $student..
can you please suggest correct revision. for controller and blade.
please keep in mind i was able to show all data from student table.

Comment: @iMatt, in your blade, what is the variable for a single student? I assume `$studeng` but you should use the variable in your blade loop. If possible please paste your working blade template.

Comment: ok here is my controller, and blade.
___
Controller: 
public function index()
    {
       $finddata = Student::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
      return view('students.index')->with('finddata', $finddata);
    }
________________
Blade: for index:
 <a href="student/{{$finddata->id}}">{{$finddata->name}}</a>
<p class="card-text">{{$finddata->id}}</p>             
above blade is showing all students name and id... when i click on any name it is showing more information like class,section etc. in show blade... there in show blade want to see family information too.

Comment: Then it should be `$finddata->family->mobile_no` etc. Again, I suggest you use standard names like students, student etc to avoid confusion in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
class student extends Model
{

    public function familyId(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Family::class,'family_id');
    }

}
```

when you click on student name it will redirect to **student/{id}**

**route**

Route::get('student/{id}', 'StudentController@show');

**student controller**

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $student = student::find($id);
    return view('student.show')->with('student', $student); 
}
```

**student.show.blade file**

```
Mobile no: {{ $student->familyId->mobile_no }}
Profession: {{ $student->familyId->profession }}
```

Comment: i already have controller to find data which i mentioned in question, i just want to show family information, when i click on student name. can you please suggest code for controller and blade?